# Error running 'sbt start-device'

Tags: android, scala, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I'm trying to get set-up with sbt and the sbt android-plugin on Mac OS 10.6.6. I installed all of the files and am able to launch the Android SDK manager from the command line. The android-plugin will create an sbt project.

However, when I try to run `sbt start-device`, I get the following error:

`Error running aapt-generate: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set ANDROID_SDK_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT or ANDROID_HOME`

But if I run `echo $ANDROID_HOME`, I get `/Users/paul/opt/android-sdk-mac_x86`

And the android-sdk-mac_x86/tools folder is in my path. What gives?

Comment: On my system $ANDROID_HOME is not set and the android-plugin runs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you set `$ANDROID_HOME`, but have you `export`ed it?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I hadn't. Now I'm getting a brand new error, but I think I can cope with the path problem.